Force Compose Text to respect other Composable
I'm trying to achieve the shown layout. The green circle should be on the right side of the red Text with a padding of 16dp. The green circle should always be visible on the screen and top aligned with the Text. Longer texts should lead to a multiline Text.
Any clues how to achieve this behavior?


When you but both the text and the circlce in a Row you can use horizontalArrangement to specify how much space there should be between them. The elements in a row will by default be aligned to the top.
By default the first composable will take as much space as it needs, possibly displacing all following composables. To prevent that use the modifier weight(1f, false) on the Text so that it can only take up as much of the space that the unweighted other composables in the row (YourCircle) leave. Set the second parameter to false so that it only takes up that much space if it really needs it.
The Text will automatically break into multiple lines when it doesn't fit in a single line.
Put together that will result in something like this:
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
) {
    Text(
        text = "your possibly very long text",
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false),
    )
    YourCircle()
}

